# How to Get value from other table if its connected via foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql, heidisql

I'm working on a bugreport database.
 there are multiple tables but 2 relevant for this question.The 2 tables are : **Hibajegyzek** and **Users**

We wanna work mainly on the **Hibajegyzek** table therefore we made a foreign key 
user_ID  which references to the **Users** Table.

I need to "pair" Users.ceg_ID to this user_ID Foreign key

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ as a good start to help you understand joins.,  `Select * from Users U INNER JOIN hibajegyzek H on U.CEG_ID = H.User_ID`  I would also ask that when asking questions be sure to post sample data, table structure and expected results to help clarify the question. (and what you have tried!)

Comment: I think you just need `select * from Users u inner join Hibajegyzek 
 h on u.ceg_ID=h.user_id`

Comment: Thank you for the Link @xQbert . I gonna keep in mind whenever i ask a new question. this was a desprete attempt since i have not used this site much.Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

based on https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/
what was provided by @xQbert
This was the thing i was looking for.

```
SELECT * FROM Hibajegyzek LEFT OUTER JOIN Users ON Hibajegyzek.user_ID = Users.user_ID
```